# using a variable name with a column name in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've a piece of code in my product model where I assign values to columns by fetching from s3. The column names includes a counter "i" as well -

The 3 sample column names are -

```
pic1_file_name
pic2_file_name
pic3_file_name
```

The problematic code is -

```
  prod = Product.find(id)
  i=1
  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  bucket=s3.buckets['bucket_name']
       bucket.objects.each do |obj|
          prod.("pic"+"#{i}".to_s+"_file_name")=obj.key[45..1]
          # the above line give a syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input
          prod.("pic"+"#{i}".to_s+"_file_name").to_sym   = obj.key[45..-1]
          # The above line gives an error undefined method `call' for #<Product:0x7773f18>
          prod.send("pic"+"#{i}".to_s+"_file_name")=obj.key[45..-1]
          # The above gives syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting end-of-input
          i+=1
       end
    prod.save
```

Could you please advise as to how should I structure my column name with a variable so that I can assign a value to it without having to type 15 separate columns every time.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would suggest to pick either concatenation or string templating instead of mixing the two. Eg. `"pic#{i}_file_name"` or `"pic" + i.to_s + "_file_name"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got the last one right. You see, when doing

```
obj.pic1_file_name = 'foo'
```

you're actually calling method `pic1_file_name=`, not `pic1_file_name`. That line is equivalent to this:

```
obj.pic1_file_name=('foo')
```

With that in mind, your last line becomes

```
prod.send("pic#{i}_file_name=", obj.key[45..-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the send method to call a method from a string:

```
prod.send("pic#{i}_file_name") # to read

prod.send("pic#{i}_file_name=", obj.key[45..-1]) # to assign
```

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. I've tried this just now, but this gives me syntax error while opening the webpage itself. The error is in 'product.rb:148: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end prod.send("pic#{i}_file_name") = obj.key[45..-1] ^'

Comment: Sorry, that was to read the value, I edit the post to show assignment as well.

Comment: Huge help for me in rails 5.2.  Thanks